# Elasticsearch Hybrid Query - Always returning a score of 0

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I’m currently trying to do a hybrid search on two indexes: a full text index and knn_vector (word embeddings) index. Currently, over 10’000 documents from Wikipedia are indexed on an ES stack, indexed on both of these fields (see mapping: “content”, “embeddings”). The queries are well known n-grams (1,2,3) that should yield results (words are taken from the wikipedia pages that are indexed).

It is also important to note that the knn_vector index is defined as a nested object.

This is the current **mapping** of the items indexed:

```
mapping = {
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                "knn": True,
                "knn.space_type": "cosinesimil"
            }
        },
       "mappings": {
        "dynamic": 'strict', 
        "properties": {
            "elasticId": 
                { 'type': 'text' },
            "owners": 
                { 'type': 'text' },
            "type": 
                { 'type': 'keyword' },
            "accessLink": 
                { 'type': 'keyword' },
            "content": 
                { 'type': 'text'}, 
    "embeddings": {
                'type': 'nested', 
                "properties": {
                  "vector": {
                    "type": "knn_vector", 
                    "dimension": VECTOR_DIM, 
                          },
                    },
    },
}
```

My goal is to compare the query scores on both indexes to understand if one is more efficient than the other (full text vs. knn_vectors), and how elastic chooses to return an object from based on the score of each index.

I understand I could simply split the queries (two separate queries), but ideally, we might want to use a hybrid search of this type in production.

This is the current **query** that searches on both full text and the knn_vectors:

```
def MakeHybridSearch(query):
    query_vector = convert_to_embeddings(query)
    result = elastic.search({
        "explain": True, 
        "profile": True, 
        "size": 2,
        "query": {
        "function_score": { #function_score
        "functions": [
            {
          "filter": { 
              "match": { 
                  "text": {
                      "query": query,
                      'boost': "5",  
                      }, 
                    }, 
                  },
            "weight": 2
          },
          {
          "filter": { 
              'script': {
                'source': 'knn_score',
                'params': {
                  'field': 'doc_vector',
                  'vector': query_vector,
                  'space_type': "l2"
                      }
                  }
                  },
                  "weight": 4
              }
          ],
          "max_boost": 5,
          "score_mode": "replace",
          "boost_mode": "multiply",
          "min_score": 5
          }
        }
      }, index='files_en', size=1000)
```

The current problem is that all queries are not returning anything.
**Result**:

```
{
"took": 3,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
    "total": {
        "value": 0,
        "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
},
```

Even when the query does return a response, it returns hits with a **score of 0 (score =0)**.

Is there an error in the query structure ? Could this be on the mapping side ? If not, is there a better of way of doing this ?

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I've seen issues similar to this when a solution doesn't allow for prefiltering prior to running k-NN and requires k-NN be run prior to filters. This often leads to null set results as none of the hits from the initial k-NN align with the subsequent filters.

Here is an option that might help as it allows for prefiltering prior to k-NN: https://medium.com/gsi-technology/scalable-semantic-vector-search-with-elasticsearch-e79f9145ba8e

Answer (score 0):

now, aws elasticsearch support post-filtering.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/knn.html

The sampe query in the page is

```
{
    "size": 2,
    "query": {
        "knn": {
            "my_vector2": {"vector": [2, 3, 5, 6], "k": 2}
        }
    },
    "post_filter": {
        "range": {
            "price": {"gte": 6, "lte": 10}
        }
    }
}
```

aws elasticsearch also support pre-filtering using 'script_score' (but it is different from 'script_score' in original elasticsearch)

https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch-docs/docs/knn/knn-score-script/

The sample query in the page is

```
{
    "size": 2,
    "query": {
        "script_score": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "filter": {
                        "term": {
                            "color": "BLUE"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "script": {
                "lang": "knn",
                "source": "knn_score",
                "params": {
                    "field": "my_binary",
                    "query_value": "U29tZXRoaW5nIEltIGxvb2tpbmcgZm9y",
                    "space_type": "hammingbit"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30489526)